# Calling out the public member variables

Tags: c++, class

This is my class function

```
class Employee
{
   private:
      string ename;
      double esalary;
   public:
      Employee(string nm = "", double sal = 0.0)
      {
            ename = nm;
            esalary = sal;
      }
      string getName()
      { return ename;}
      double getSalary()
      {  return esalary;}
};
#endif
```

and now my incomplete body...

```
#include "employee.h"

using namespace std;

Employee read_employee()
{
string name;
cout << "Please enter the name: ";
getline(cin, name);
double salary;
cout << "Please enter the salary: ";
cin >> salary;
Employee r(name, salary);
return r;
} 

int main()
{
Employee emp(string name,double salary);
read_employee();
}
```

I am wondering how do i call the "getName or getSalary" functions from the class. I am used to the class objects without parameters.

Comment: `emp.getName()` and `emp.getSalary()` should do the trick

Comment: No, I tried. Doesn't work

Comment: Your main function consists of declaring a function and then calling another function, but not using the return value.

Comment: @user3345335 "Didn't work" is not a helpful problem description, especially if you don't show even show us the code that didn't work.

Comment: @wqrahd: You'd think, but the devious thing is that `read_employee` is not a member function of `Employee`, but a global function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Employee emp = read_employee();
```

Instead of:

```
Employee emp(string name,double salary);
read_employee();
```

And then you can say:

`emp.getName()` and `emp.getSalary()`

Your problem is that your `read_employee()` function is a global function. That is, it's not necessarily attached to any specific `Employee` instance. If you added it to your `Employee` class, things might work a little better:

```
class Employee
{
   private:
      string ename;
      double esalary;
   public:
      Employee(string nm = "", double sal = 0.0)
      {
            ename = nm;
            esalary = sal;
      }
      string getName()
      { return ename;}
      double getSalary()
      {  return esalary;}
      void read_employee()
      {
         cout << "Please enter the name: ";
         getline(cin, ename);
         cout << "Please enter the salary: ";
         cin >> esalary;

      } 
};
```

And then in `main`:

```
#include "employee.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   Employee emp;
   emp.read_employee();
   cout << emp.getName() << endl;
   cout << emp.getSalary() << endl;
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm not doing any error checking at all, so we just have to assume the user will play nice with his/her inputs.

Comment: Well I am supposed to make read_employee() function to use the class, but not be part of the class. That's why i put the function outside of the int main instead of inside the public class

Comment: @user3345335: In that case simply say `Employee emp = read_employee();` in `main` instead of what you have now. Then you should be able to call your other functions.

Comment: Yup that works now thanks :) going to do my test harnessing now

Answer (score 0):

As Chris mentions, you are not assigning the return values of your functions to anything.  You want something like:

Employee emp = read_employee("Johnny", 45000);

Which will create an employee object in your function, then return it.  That returned object is then assigned to emp.